# Transforming non-structured data (concatenated strings of text) into consumable, readable format / extracting datapoints from strings

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract specific datapoints from string of text and have a hard time figuring out how to do so.

---

What I need to achieve is to extract **dates** from a specific *string*.
The string structure is as follows:
*Product: XX1, Made by: WWW ZZZ, Date: YYYY-MM-DD;* and it can be repeated multiple times (see the screenshot below). There are three different product types (lets say: Car_VW, Car_Tesla, Car_PS - there are no records with other product types) and **date** has to be extracted separately for each one of them.

Moreover, one product type can appear few times (up to three times) in this *string* so the date needs to be stored separately for each instance of its appearing.

[image: Columns E - M show what I need to achieve based on data in column C]

Columns E - M show what I need to achieve based on data in column C

I came up following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1)>0,FIND("Product",$C4,1)=1),MID(MID($C4,FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1),LEN($C4)-FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1)),FIND("Date: ",MID($C4,FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1),LEN($C4)-FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1)),1)+6,10),"no go"),"")
```

Which works only for first "iterations" of each product.
[image: dates after formula is applied]

Looking at how the data in column C is formatted, do you guys think it's possible to write something that would return correct values for each iteration/loop? If so, a little help would be much appreciated. If anyone knows a better way to do it, please let me know. Would using VBA be a better approach?

Comment: I would definitely go the VBA route on this one. Do you have much experience with it?

Comment: Yep. It would be a better option but I started with formulas and I just couldn't stomach the fact that this problem could beat me. Anyway, I've finally came up with correct formula. Will post it below if anyone ever had a similar task and somehow ended up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's a better approach but it will handle any number of products/appearances and creates corresponding row 3 headings as well as a temporary table of normalized data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub normalize()

    Const COL_TEXT = 3
    Const RE_PATTERN = "Product: ?([^,]+), Made.*?Date: ?([\d-]+)"

    ' use a regular expression for pattern matching
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With Regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(" & RE_PATTERN & ")"
    End With

    ' Us dictionary to count dates for each Product
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsTmp As Worksheet, iTmp As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' create temp sheet to store table
    Set wsTmp = wb.Sheets.Add
    iTmp = 0

    ' scan sheet
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim sText As String, sProduct As String, sDate As String
    Dim matches As Object, match As Object, key As Variant
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim iBlocks As Long, t0 as single
    t0 = Timer

    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, COL_TEXT).End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print iLastRow

    ' scan sheet with text
    For iRow = 4 To iLastRow
        sText = ws.Cells(iRow, COL_TEXT) ' text in  C
        'Debug.Print s

        ' extract product and date
        If Regex.test(sText) Then
            Set matches = Regex.Execute(sText)
            For Each match In matches

                sProduct = match.submatches(1)
                sDate = match.submatches(2)

                ' update dictionary
                If dict.exists(sProduct) Then
                    dict(sProduct) = dict(sProduct) + 1
                Else
                    dict.Add sProduct, 1
                End If

                ' store result temporarily
                iTmp = iTmp + 1
                wsTmp.Cells(iTmp, 1) = iRow
                wsTmp.Cells(iTmp, 2) = sProduct
                wsTmp.Cells(iTmp, 3) = dict(sProduct)
                wsTmp.Cells(iTmp, 4) = sDate
            Next
        End If

        ' increase no of blocks if required
        For Each key In dict.keys
           If dict(key) > iBlocks Then
               iBlocks = dict(key)
           End If
           dict(key) = 0
        Next
    Next

    ' create headings in row 3 for each block/product
    c = 5 ' start in E
    For n = 1 To iBlocks
       For Each key In dict.keys
          If n = 1 Then dict(key) = c ' reuse dict for column no
          ws.Cells(3, c) = key & " Loop" & n
          c = c + 1
       Next
    Next

    ' scan down temp result sheet
    For iRow = 1 To iTmp
        r = wsTmp.Cells(iRow, 1)
        sProduct = wsTmp.Cells(iRow, 2)
        n = wsTmp.Cells(iRow, 3)
        sDate = wsTmp.Cells(iRow, 4)

        ' fill in correct cell on original
        c = dict(sProduct) ' start column
        ws.Cells(r, c + (n - 1) * dict.count) = sDate
    Next
    wsTmp.Delete

    ' end
    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells(3, 3).Select
    MsgBox iTmp & " Product/Dates Extracted in " & int(Timer - t0) & " secs"

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! It might need some tweaking 'cause it doesn't return all values but I think it's a good start. Here's the dummy data I used on this macro:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApT_H-BlvpRSjcBbLpPAAc7RTgubKg?e=FamlYm

I've already pasted the formula that returns all instances of dates per products and it runs surprisingly fast (tested on +200 000 records of production data - took less than a minute) and it dynamically adjusts to values in headers.

Comment: @Whichmann Tweaked. From your screenshots I thought each product was a separate line.

Comment: great stuff. You solution is far better than my formula. Next time I'll deal with similar taks, I'll go with your macro as it's more flexible and cleaner to read. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I've completed the formula. Here goes this abomination:

```
=IFERROR(MID(MID($C4,FIND("XXX",SUBSTITUTE($C4,LEFT(E$3,6),"XXX",RIGHT(E$3,1))),LEN($C4)-FIND(LEFT(E$3,6),$C4,1)),FIND("Date: ",MID($C4,FIND("XXX",SUBSTITUTE($C4,LEFT(E$3,6),"XXX",RIGHT(E$3,1))),LEN($C4)-FIND("XXX",SUBSTITUTE($C4,LEFT(E$3,6),"XXX",RIGHT(E$3,1)))),1)+6,10),"")
```

^works for a table structured like the one in the initial post

Comment: I think you only need to match or countif with wildcard for this exercise, if possible let's upload fake data!

Comment: Not sure how to do it this way to be honest.
Link to dummy data:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApT_H-BlvpRSjcBbLpPAAc7RTgubKg?e=FamlYm

Comment: please share file! canot download.